# mockito anyList of a given size

Tags: java, list, mockito

I'm verifying with mockito that a method has been called. The method:

```
public void createButtons(final List<Button> buttonsConfiguration) {...}
```

Since It doesn't matter which list is passed I verify that the method is called as follows:

```
verify(mock).createButtons(Matchers.anyListOf(Button.class));
```

But, the size of the `List` is important. So, it doesn't matter which `List` but the list has to have X elements.

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

One way is to use a Captor

```
ArgumentCaptor<List> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);
verify(mock).createButtons(captor.capture());
assertEquals(x, captor.getValue().size()); // if expecting single list
assertEquals(x, captor.getValues().size()); // if expecting multiple lists
```

See http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#15 for the documentation.

You could also use a custom argument matcher. The documentation shows an example that does exactly what you want:

http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html

```
 class IsListOfTwoElements extends ArgumentMatcher<List> {
     public boolean matches(Object list) {
         return ((List) list).size() == 2;
     }
 }
 
 List mock = mock(List.class);
 when(mock.addAll(argThat(new IsListOfTwoElements()))).thenReturn(true);
 mock.addAll(Arrays.asList("one", "two"));
 verify(mock).addAll(argThat(new IsListOfTwoElements()));
```

You could, for instance, also add a constructor so you can specify list size desired, etc.

Comment: Future readers: Beware that, despite being in the Mockito documentation verbatim, this example ArgumentMatcher isn't tolerant of `null` or non-`List` types. This can cause NPE or ClassCastException. A more comprehensive solution may use `TypeSafeMatcher<List>`, or a guard like `if (!(list instanceof List)) return false`.

Comment: this ArgumentCaptor<List> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class); cannot accept a typed list no? something like ArgumentCaptor List<String>

Comment: Tedious. See gertas' answer below

Answer (score 50):

With Mockito 3.x, and 2.1+ you can use Java 8 lambda expressions:

```
verify(mock).createButtons(argThat(list -> list.size() == 5));
```

With Mockito 2.1 and below similar:

```
verify(mock).createButtons(argThat(list -> ((List) list).size() == 5));
```

To check emptiness it is even easier:

```
verify(mock).createButtons(argThat(List::isEmpty));
```

Comment: should be the top answer for simplicity

Comment: Fabulous. Thank you. Please upvote this to infinity

Answer (score 25):

Hamcrest (hamcrest-library dependency) provides a simpler way.

```
verify(mock).addAll((List) argThat(IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize(4)));
```

or with static `import org.hamcrest.collection.IsCollectionWithSize;`

```
verify(mock).addAll((List) argThat(hasSize(4)));
```

Comment: This will work if your argument is `Collection`. If you have `List` you need to cast.

Comment: Yep, and just to clarify: you would have to cast it like this: `verify(mock).addAll((List)argThat(IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize(4)));`

Comment: May require a new dependency on hamcrest-library if all you have is hamcrest-core and the import doesn't work, FWIW.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working example for me:

```
  List<Object> objects = mock(List.class);
  when(objects.size()).thenReturn(1000);
```